# Prevent navigating when double press button quickly react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Hi I am have code with react-navigation.
I want to prevent navigating twice when clicking a button quickly. This code is working perfectly.
This is my **SignedOut** Navigation

```
export const SignedOut = StackNavigator({
    Onboarding: {
        screen: Onboarding,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Onboarding",
            header: null
        }
    },
    InitApp: {
        screen: InitApp,
            navigationOptions: {
            title: "Init",
            header: null
        }
    },
    Auth: {
        screen: Auth,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Auth",
            header: null
        }
    }
});
const navigateOnce = (getStateForAction) => (action, state) => {
        const {type, routeName} = action;
        return (
        state &&
            type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE &&
            routeName === state.routes[state.routes.length - 1].routeName
    ) ? null : getStateForAction(action, state);       
};
SignedOut.router.getStateForAction = navigateOnce(SignedIn.router.getStateForAction);
```

It is working perfectly. But today I want to add params to StackNavigator and **navigateOnce** didn't work!

The code like this:

```
export const SignedOuts = (firstTime = false) =>
    StackNavigator({
        Onboarding: {
        screen: Onboarding,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Onboarding",
            header: null
        }
    },
    InitApp: {
        screen: InitApp,
            navigationOptions: {
            title: "Init",
            header: null
        }
    },
    Auth: {
        screen: Auth,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Auth",
            header: null
        }
     }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: firstTime ? "Onboarding" : "Auth",            
    }
)
```

It said: **Cannot read property 'getStateForAction' of undefined**

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `navigate` method, and you want to prevent navigation twice(i.e. prevent a screen from being pushed twice), then, you should set the `key` of the screen.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate({'key':'NewsFeed', routeName:'NewsFeedScreen'})
```

I have not used routers with react-navigation and the document seems pretty scarce. My suggestion would be to go through the code of `StackRouter`[here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/routers/StackRouter.js) and look how you can pass a unique key to each screen. This should prevent the problem you are facing

Comment: It's not prevented. It throw new Error: 'should not push route with duplicated key SignIn'

Comment: I assume you implemented this solution: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/271#issuecomment-307607245

If not, then, please go through this discussion for a potential solution